# Poniendo un web site dentro de una app Ionic

Tags: ionic3, ionic-framework

Estoy trabajando con Ionic 3, lo que pretendo es poner un web site en una app Ionic.

Lo tengo resuelto pero en el home.html tengo un botón el cual llama una pagina en blanco y lo pone ahí, lo que necesito es que cuando abra la aplicación ya se vea la web sin un botón de intermediario.

Muestro el código que ocupo.

Home.html

```
<ion-header>


 <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      <!-- Ionic Blank -->
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="openLink()">Abrir link</button>
</ion-content>
```

Home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  // template:"<p>...loading</p>"
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private iap: InAppBrowser) {

    }
    openLink(){
      this.iap.create("https://www.ubikate.net/","_blank");
  }
  // constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser, public platform: Platform){
  //   platform.ready().then(()=>{
  //     let browser = this.iab.create('https://www.ubikate.net/');
  //     browser.show();
  //   });
  // }
}
```

¿De que manera debo de modificar para lograr lo que deseo?

Saludos!

Comment: Ya probaste el evento `ionViewDidLoad` de Ionic, donde Se ejecuta cuando la página que se cargado. Este evento solo ocurre una vez por página siendo creado. Si una página se va pero se almacena en caché, este evento no volverá a activarse en una visualización posterior. El `ionViewDidLoad` evento es un buen lugar para poner su código de configuración para la página. Podría ser una alternativa

Comment: @jecorrales Voy a investigar soy principiante en Ionic.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con el siguiente segmento de código, no tengo el ambiente disponible para realizar pruebas pero a lo mejor te pueda servir desde mi punto de vista:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  // template:"<p>...loading</p>"
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private iap: InAppBrowser) 
  {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() 
  {
      this.iap.create("https://www.ubikate.net/","_blank")
  }
}
```

Como te dije en el comentario, solo tendrias que hacer uso del evento `ionViewDidLoad`, me avisas si funciona sino tambien jeje

Comment: ¿Quedaría así en el Home.html?<ion-content padding>
  <div class="" (click)="ionViewDidLoad()">

  </div>
</ion-content>

Comment: Cuando lanzo la app, me llama a otra page y eso que ya le borre el _blank, necesito que cargue en el Load de la pagina, que no llame a otras page.

Comment: No necesitas el evento click de angular para esta funcionalidad, dado que pretendes que esta configuracion se cargue de forma automática. Como dijiste que te servia si hacias uso del evento entonces no corregí nada mas, por lo que ahora que lo leo, es obvio que te abre una nueva pagina. Dejame investigo algo y te aviso

Comment: Una pregunta, supongo que cuando haces click en el botón `<button ion-button color="primary" (click)="openLink()">Abrir link</button>` te pide abrir el navegador? o te abre una página dentro de la misma aplicacion de `Ionic`

Comment: <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      <!-- Ionic Blank -->
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  
</ion-content> Este es mi código actual y creo si funciona creare el apk y te aviso.

Comment: Ah, respondiendo tu pregunta me abre una pagina dentro de la misma app de ionic.

Comment: @PedroÁvila Te funcionó?

Comment: Ya lo probé en un mobile y efectivamente se abre en blanco y llama a otra page dentro de la app. Yo quería que cuando abro la app ahí se muestre.

Answer (score -1):

puedes probar de esta manera... en html a mí me funcionó así:

```
<ion-content center text-center>   
   <iframe src ="" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: <ion-content center text-center>   
   <iframe src ="" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
</ion-content>

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SOes. Recuerda que siempre puedes [edit] tu pubicación para agregar mas contenido, lo cual seria lo correcto. Recuerda seguir los lineamientos del articulo [mcve], y darle formato a tu código.

Comment: Hola Cleydi, deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que has cambiado? ¿por qué ese cambio soluciona el problema? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.